# how to change complex cypher queries to simple query in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i want to find the users with max number of friends and min number of friends.
here is my query:

```
"start n=node:users({query}) match p=n-[?:Friend*]->x 
with distinct n,count(distinct x) as  cnt  "
+ "start n=node:users({query}) match p=n-[?:Friend*]->x 
with distinct n,count(distinct x) as cnt1, min(cnt) as minnumber "
+ "start n=node:users({query}) match p=n-[?:Friend*]->x
with distinct n,count(distinct x) as friendsNumber, max(cnt1) as 
maxnumber, minnumber  "
+ "where  friendsNumber=minnumber or friendsNumber=maxnumber  return n.name,
friendsNumber"
```

n is user and x is his friends.
but i used three nested query and i think its performance isn't good.is there another way to do this?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe querying two times would be better

```
START n=node:users({query})
MATCH n-[:Friend]->x
WITH n,count(x) as cnt
RETURN n, cnt order by cnt desc limit 1;

START n=node:users({query})
MATCH n-[:Friend]->x
WITH n,count(x) as cnt
RETURN n, cnt order by cnt asc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use variable length paths here. Also no optional relationships as you are interested in people with friends.

I think running two queries might be most sensible here:

```
start n=node:users({query}) 
match p=n-[:Friend]->x
with ID(n),count(distinct x) as  cnt
with max(cnt) as max,min(cnt) as min

start n=node:users({query}) 
match p=n-[:Friend]->x
with n,count(distinct x) as  cnt
where cnt=max or cnt=min
return n.name
```

Something like this should also work: http://console.neo4j.org/r/xf3hm0

```
start n=node(*) 
match p=n-[:KNOWS]-x 
with n,count(distinct x) as  cnt 
with collect([n,cnt]) as data, max(cnt) as max,min(cnt) as min 
return extract(pair in 
   filter(pair in data 
     where tail(pair)=max OR tail(pair)=min) : 
   head(pair)) as person
```